# nginx_status -> Exception: Server localhost is not responsible

Tags: java, jsp, nginx, struts, action

In my project are using: Java6, Struts 1, JSP.

In a some.jsp page there are several lines of code:

```
try {               
ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
  public String call() throws Exception {
    String rez = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString((
      new java.net.URL("http://" + server + ":8080/nginx_status")).openStream());
    return rez;
        }
    });
 exService.execute(task);
 String rez = (String) task.get(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 if (rez == null) System.out.println("Server " + server + " is not responsible in 300 ms");
 System.out.println("Server " + server + " status: " +rez);
} catch (Exception ex) {
 System.out.println("Server " + server + " is not responsible");
    }
   }    
} catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.print("Status information: cannot find servers adress");
}
```

After executing of code, on a console are displayed the following line of code:

> Server localhost is not responsible

What could be the problem?

Comment: Code in JSP makes the problem to the code. Incomplete code makes the question off-topic.

Comment: If you catch an exception, printing the type and message instead of meaningless messages would really help to find the cause of the problem. By the way, we have 2015. You should really start using Generics.

Comment: @Dylan: Hi try accessing the url in browser "http://<server-name>:8080/nginx_status may be it running on some different port. Do you mind if I check if I ask you why you want to check ngnix status like this?